# A better way to check dictionary for values

Tags: swift, swift2

I am currently put in a project that has some beastly code snippet that checks particular values in a dictionary:

```
guard let userDictionary = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("asdf"), _ = userDictionary["baseUrl"] as? String, _ = userDictionary["refreshToken"] as? String, _ = userDictionary["oauthCode"] as? String, _ = userDictionary["oauthKey"] as? String else { return false }
return true
```

Are there better ways to do this, such as using something like `contains`?

Comment: Do you want to know whether the "baseURL" key exists and has a String value, or merely whether it exists? Also, is this a Swift dictionary or an NSDictionary?

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but you should probably have a `User` model object that has these values as optionals and then go from there.

Comment: @matt good point. I don't know yet - this is part of an existing app that needs to be brought over to Swift2, so I'm not certain if he needs to check if it's a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *all* you want to know is whether the dictionary contains a list of keys, you can test it like this:

```
Set(d.keys).isSupersetOf(["hey", "ho"])
```

But if you want to know, for each key, whether the corresponding value is of a certain type that is not the value type of the dictionary (i.e. it requires casting), then the way you are doing it is the only good way.